# Having a task performed at a certain time

Tags: java, time

So I am using the Robot class in Java to perform a task automatically during the night. I need it to do the task at 1:10:10 am, but it isn't working with my tests. I make the time match with current time, but add a minute for testing. It doesn't perform the task. Here is my (edited, made the integer a boolean now also) main code:

```
private void startStopButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    String time = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(time);
    press = true;
    while(press == true){
        if(time.equals("09:39:10")){
            System.out.println("well its time");
            try {
                rightClick();
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                click(573, 255);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                click(648, 294);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                keyPress();
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                press = false;
            } catch (AWTException | InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my methods:

```
private void rightClick() throws AWTException{
    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_5);
    bot.delay(500);
    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_5);
    bot.delay(1000);
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
    bot.delay(500);
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
}

private void click(int x, int y) throws AWTException{
    Robot rob = new Robot();
    rob.mouseMove(x, y);
    rob.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    rob.delay(500);
    rob.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
}

private void keyPress() throws AWTException{
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    r.delay(500);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    r.delay(500);
}
```

So, I hope anyone can enlighten me on why it isn't doing the task. :)

Comment: Have you debugged it? Are you sure your date string is in the right format?

Comment: what is `press` above? where is it declared and initialized?

Comment: The `press` is an integer, and is added 1 everytime I press the startStop button. Yes, I have made sure my data string is in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

There are two debug points you can follow up with -

1. `press` should be initialized with `press = 0` to meet the while condition. Though that seems to be an infinite loop post that. Unless your code reaches an exception.
2. Within your `if` condition, try changing to

   ```
   if(sdf.format(cal.getTime()).equals("08:15:10")   // notice the starting 0
   ```

since you are comparing two strings and not an integer value here.

Comment: Still not working. `while(press == 1){
            if(sdf.format(cal.getTime()).equals("08:36:10")){
                System.out.println("well its time");` `int press = 0;`

Comment: It's not even printing it.

Comment: @BrennanB. Could you please update the question with te complete method/class then.

Comment: @BrennanB. Also, note the time specified by you would only execute at 08:15:10 am in the morning and not  at 1:10:10 am as mentioned in the question.

Comment: I will update the question. I just had the time set to current time and added a minute for testing purposes.

Comment: I feel like it is the while loop that is causing this. I can't click the button again, and I can't close it unless I go to task manager and end it. The while loop might be lagging it too much.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my own question! It turns out that it only checked the time when I press the button, so it never checked the time after that. Here is the fixed code:

```
private void startStopButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    press = true;
    System.out.println(press);
    while(press == true){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        String time = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(time);
        if(time.equals("10:27:10")){
            System.out.println("well its time");
            try {
                rightClick();
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                click(573, 255);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                click(648, 294);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                keyPress();
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                press = false;
            } catch (AWTException | InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            break;
        }
   }
}
```